# True or False; Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Given $T: V \to W$ with $V,W$ being Hilbert Spaces. We always have $\| T^ *\| = \| T \|$.

I think it is true because of [Riesz' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), but I am not sure if a proof is necessary.

*EDIT*: In case notations have conflicts. $T^*$ is adjoint of $T$

Comment: IIRC you don't need Riesz.

Comment: IIRC? What is that?

Comment: A proof is *always* necessary.

Comment: @Cake: IIRC = "If I recall correctly"

Comment: The reason I asked is because the question previous says *Every bounded sequence in $R^n$ has a convergent subsequence* and it is true by BW Theorem, and we were only given 3 inches by 6 inches to answer...

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Norm_of_Adjoint

Comment: @sizz What "last step"?

Comment: Oh wait, never mind, it is an inequality. My bad

Answer (score 4):

Only Cauchy-Schwarz is needed to prove that
$$
\Vert z\Vert=\sup\limits_{\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}|\langle z,y\rangle|
$$
Then we get
$$
\begin{align}
\Vert T^*\Vert
&=\sup\limits_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}\Vert T^*(x)\Vert\\
&=\sup\limits_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}\sup\limits_{\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}|\langle T^*(x),y\rangle|\\
&=\sup\limits_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}\sup\limits_{\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}|\overline{\langle T(y),x\rangle}|\\
&=\sup\limits_{\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\sup\limits_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}|\langle T(y),x\rangle|\\
&=\sup\limits_{\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\Vert T(y)\Vert\\
&=\Vert T\Vert
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\|T^\ast(x)\|^2=\langle T^\ast(x),T^\ast(x)\rangle\leq \|x\|\|T\|\|T^\ast(x)\|\quad  \forall\ x\in V,$$

where we used the inequality of Cauchy-Schwarz and that $T\in L(V,W)$ (this hypothesis should be added). So

$$\|T^\ast(x)\|\leq \|T\|\|x\|\quad  \forall\ x\neq 0, $$

$T^\ast\in L(V,W)$ and $\|T^\ast\|\leq \|T\|$. Similarly,

$$\|T(x)\|^2=\langle T(x),T(x)\rangle=\langle x,T^\ast(T(x))\rangle\leq \|x\|\|T^\ast\|\|T(x)\|.$$

Thus, $\|T\|\leq \|T^\ast\|$ and follows the inequality.